# Create desktop shortcut to exe with argument with Inno Setup

Tags: python, inno-setup, shortcut-file

I'm trying to create an installer for a Python script with Inno Setup.
My goal is to have a single installer.

With Inno Setup, I packed my Python script, an embedded version of Python, and an icon.

But I don't figure how to tell to Inno Setup that my app is a .exe with an argument like:

```
.\python.exe .\myScript.py
```

I want to create an icon that will execute `".\python.exe .\myScript.py"`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you don't plan to allow end users to modify that script file, you might generate a self contained executable via PyInstaller, https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a desktop icon that will execute installed `python.exe` with your script as an argument, add an entry to [`[Icons]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection) of your Inno Setup script:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{autodesktop}\My Program"; Filename: "python.exe"; \
    Parameters: ".\myScript.py"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you compiled your python file to a .exe? Or is it a .py?
The best way to setup Inno Setup is to use its inbuilt installer creation wizard. It steps you through exactly what you need to do. Then you can go back in and change the code after if you're not happy.

Comment: No It is a .py.
I'm using the creation wizard, but i'm not able to select python.exe with myscript.py as an argument. I cant only slect python.exe without argument

Comment: I see what you mean. However this is impractical. When you are at the stage of preparing a program for distribution, the best thing to do is to compile it to a `.exe` , `.app`, or `.sh` file before packing it into an installer. That way anyone on any device can open your program. The best method for doing this is to use pyinstaller. There are plenty of tutorials online about how to use it, and it's relatively straightforward.